# Xcode 4. Adding tableView to tab bar application

Tags: uitableview, xcode4, uitabbar

Ive created a new tab bar application in xcode 4 and it has generated a mainwindow.xib, firstView.xib, secondView.xib and viewController classes for each xib.

I would like to add a tableView to the firstView.xib, so i have added a UITableViewController class to the project and Xcode generated a new tableViewController.xib which displays a tableView.

How do i hook it up so the TableView is loaded into the firstView in xcode 4.

EDIT:

Ok, I've tried adding a tableViewController to the firstView.xib and setting its class name and nib properties to the name of my TableViewController class, but its not visible when the app runs.

Cheers

Comment: you need to add an IBOulet to your firstView.h

Answer (score 0):

in firstView.h, add an IBOutlet which will represent the TableViewController
in firstView.xib, link the tableViewController to the corresponding File Owner IBOutlet
in firstView.m, in viewDidLoad method, initialize your tableViewController.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple tutorial
http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Creating_a_Simple_iOS_4_iPhone_Table_View_Application_(Xcode_4)